# Blank lines in list in Redmine

Tags: wiki, redmine, textile

This seems so stupidly simple, but I can't figure it out.  I'd like to make a list like this in my Redmine project wiki:

1. Really complicated item

   Line 3
2. Next complicated item

Basically, I want to have blank lines in my list without restarting numbering.  How do I do this?  It seems so basic; I can't believe they haven't thought of this - I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I finally figured out a good way to do this using non-breaking spaces:

```
# Really complicated item
 &nbsp;
 Line 3
 &nbsp;
# Next complicated item
```

Seems that I found a part of HTML that isn't banned by Redmine...  If that changes, you can still work around it using marapet's solution, but for the item after Line 3 you have to copy/paste a non-breaking space (a different character from normal space) instead of just pressing spacebar between the "@ @" symbols.

Comment: Don't tell the Redmine devs; they seem more interested in removing such functionality!  http://www.redmine.org/issues/843

Answer (score 5):

Redmine produces this html:

```
<ol>
<li>Really complicated item

    <p>Line 3</p>
    </li>
    <li>Next complicated item</li>
</ol>
```

By adding `@ @` as the second (empty) line :

```
# Really complicated item
 @ @
 Line 3
# Next complicated item
```

the html generated is:

```
<ol>
    <li>Really complicated item
<br/>
 <code> </code><br/> Line 3</li>
    <li>Next complicated item</li>
</ol>
```

which should display as you'd like (at least with the default theme), but semantically it's of course non-sense.

Comment: Clever... works for the example you gave, but how to add a blank line *after* the Line 3 and *before* #2 "Next Complicated Item"?  Using "@ @" after Line 3 didn't seem to work for that.